how to move a 5 star e pole to a flat surface on my shotgun mesh and topology recommendation?
Here is a 5 star e pole on my mesh,
I am trying to move it to a flat surface

Here is the mesh of the shotgun I have made so far

Here is the reference image I am basing my design of

You see the tricky bit is the topology for the pump underneath the barrel
Also I would like the moved pole to look somewhat to this pole I moved previously as yuo can see below

Other angles of my mesh below


